# How to order the results of a ForeignKey relationship in a Django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this models in Django

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

and this ModelForm

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

when I use this form in a template, everything works fine, but the country list in the `<select>` appears disordered. How can I order it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [ordering](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) property:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
```

If you set the ordering to the Country class, it shall display them as you want.

Comment: Thank you for down voting me without any reason!

Comment: I agree with @cx42net. If our answers aren't good for you, just explain yourself, in a way that we can actually help you

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the other person that answer my question down voting you to make his answers appears first. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @segaco : I'm not accusing you :)

Comment: the important thing is that you got a solution for your problem :)

Comment: I don't think this is a correct solution, since this forces ordering on all queries of the model. One reason is that all queries on this model will be sorted even if not needed. Second reason is that it doesn't solve the problem if there are two forms with different requirements for ordering.

Answer (score 13):

If you can't or don't want to use the ordering attribute in class Meta of model, you also can do this:

You need make a Form object, something like:

```
from django import forms
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all().order_by('name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

[field types for formsmodels](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)

Comment: If you want to order by a foreign field of the related model (i.e. if Country.name itself is a foreign key), you can use double-underscores: `order_by('name__fieldXYZ')`. See https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/order_by_related_model.html. I needed that as the name of the Dropdown-Items that I want to order was constructed solely from foreign keys.

Answer (score 11):

There's 2 good answers here, but I wanted to retain `help_text`, `blank`, and other settings from the model without having to repeat them and also not change the default ordering on the model.  Here's what I did:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].queryset = self.fields['country'].queryset.order_by('name')
```

Essentially I just updated the queryset on the automatically added field to order the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this into class Meta, inside class Person:

```
ordering = ['country']
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Comment: This would sort by country id, not by country name.

Answer (score 0):

**In view.py**
**First:** you create the form

```
form = YourForm(request.POST)
```

**Later your set the query:**

```
form.fields['country '].queryset = YourDBTable.objects.all().order_by('Your_Attr')
```