# How to sort source argument for nested serializer field in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have 2 models: `Page` and `Section`. A `Page` object may have 1-to-many `Section` objects.
In `models.py`:

```py
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Name of the page.')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']


class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Name of the section.')
    index = models.IntegerField(blank=True, help_text='Index number to sort section.')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

`index` in a `Section` object indicates its ordering (position) among the rest of `Section` objects that have same `Page` object as their foreign key.
In `serializers.py`:

```py
class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    page = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Page.objects.all(),
                                              many=False, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ['id', 'page', 'name', 'index']


class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sections = SectionSerializer(source='section_set', many=True, required=False)  # problem is here.
    # can I do something like source="section_set.order_by('index')"
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'sections']
```

With `sections` attribute in `PageSerializer` I can get all `Section` objects that have the same `Page` object as foreign key. But not ordered by their `index` field.
When I query `Page.objects.all` using `PageSerializer` I got this result in browsable API:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Home",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":10,
            "page":1,
            "name":"second_section_for_page_1",
            "index":2
         },
         {
            "id":11,
            "page":1,
            "name":"first_section_for_page_1",
            "index":1
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "page":1,
            "name":"third_section_for_page_1",
            "index":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Profile",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":13,
            "page":2,
            "name":"second_section_for_page_2",
            "index":2
         },
         {
            "id":14,
            "page":2,
            "name":"first_section_for_page_2",
            "index":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like the result to be ordered by `index`. Like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Home",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":11,
            "page":1,
            "name":"first_section_for_page_1",
            "index":1
         },
         {
            "id":10,
            "page":1,
            "name":"second_section_for_page_1",
            "index":2
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "page":1,
            "name":"third_section_for_page_1",
            "index":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Profile",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":14,
            "page":2,
            "name":"first_section_for_page_2",
            "index":1
         },
         {
            "id":13,
            "page":2,
            "name":"second_section_for_page_2",
            "index":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can I do something like `sections = SectionSerializer(source="section_set.order_by('index')")` in `PageSerializer` class?

Comment: You can try to use `ordering` property in `Meta` in `Section` class.  It will order all `Section` queries. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062320/7320870 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering

Comment: I think I can't use ordering = ['index'] in Section model. Because I have a Section view class to list all Sections ordered by their PK (id).

Comment: Then you could write queryset in Section view that explicitly orders `Section`s by their id.

Comment: @wiaterb Thank you. I'll implement your suggestion.